# Amazon Alexa - How can I get year from my written text?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I need to convert a written number into an integer value. So, if I type twenty  fourteen or two thousand fourteen, I should be able to interpret it as 2014 in my function. I have tried AMAZON.DATE and AMAZON.NUMBER which do not work satisfactorily.

Comment: To be clear, the year is being recognized, but you either need a library to convert the spoken number text to a number or a slot that recognizes a year and returns a number, correct?

Comment: Yes, i found out the solution in one of the Amazon's built in slot type.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution, Amazon provides a built in slot type AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER which solved my purpose.